# JSP alert from the servlet URL

Tags: jsp, servlets

how to get input from the URL in the JSP page to show alert boxes  after it sets attribute http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/?inCorrect=1. I want to show an alert if `inCorrect=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try below....

```
<% String input = request.getParameter("inCorrect");
   int k = -1;
   try{
     k = Integer.parseInt(input);
   }catch(NumberFormatException e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
  if(k ==1) {
%>
 alert("message1");
<%}else{%>
 alert("message2");
<%}%>
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Your alert("message") is (invalid) part of a Java block, but needs to be inserted in the resulting HTML.